# Get highlighted variable -Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt, highlight

I am implementing an Eclipse plugin for C programmers.
I can't find a way to get the variable that the user already highlited.(The user will highlight a variable in the editor and I need to know which variable it is/variable's name/location of this variable in the editor, like line number..)
Can anyone help to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after searching in some links, I achvieved that by using the ***ISelectionProvider*** and ***ITextSelection*** Interfaces. Here a code to get the name of the highlighted variable :

```
ISelectionProvider selProvider = textEditor.getSelectionProvider();
            ITextSelection txtSel = (ITextSelection) selProvider.getSelection();
            String varName = txtSel.getText();
```